# Why is not QThread being run?

Tags: qt, qthread

I am developing an application with Qt using threads. Starting the application I launched a thread to do some work, moving the object that needs to do the work to a thread like this

```
QThread aThread;
CsvLoader csvLoader;
connect(&aThread, SIGNAL(started()), &csvLoader, SLOT(compute()));
csvLoader.moveToThread(aThread);
aThread.start();
```

which works fine at the beginning of the application. Now, I have a button in the UI that basically what I want to do is to re-run the `compute()` method from `csvLoader` by just doing

```
aThread.start();
```

however, this second call to make the thread run is not calling the slot connected to the `started()` signal.

Any idea on what could I check or what could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second call of `start()` will do nothing as `QThread` already started.

What you need to do is to connect your slot `compute()` to some signal you will emit from `onClicked()` slot (or whatever name it has). Or connect it directly to the button signal `clicked()`.
Please pay attention that you can connect several slots to same signal in same time.

Comment: But that will run in the same thread as the GUI is running isn't it? This will block the thread if `compute()` takes a long time. How can I make `compute()` is called on a separate thread while keeping the GUI responsive to user input?

Comment: @BRabbit27, you are understand qt thread a little wrong. You send signal from main thread, but slot of csvLoader will be executed in the aThread, because you moved csvLoader to it - qt will handle it. But if you will call `csvLoader.compute()` directly then it will be executed in main thread. Also be carefull about lifetime of both csvLoader and aThread.

Comment: Yes, I think I wasn't understanding the complete idea of` `moveToThread()`. After reading the doc I got your idea. Time to code !